# postgresql reload ssl conf files without restart

Tags: postgresql, ssl

Postgresql DB (9.x) on linux

Here's what the docs says:
" Docs says this: The ﬁles server.key, server.crt, root.crt, and root.crl are only examined during server start; so you must restart the server..."

Is there any work-around for this?

The docs says the same for pg_hba.conf, but there is a way to reload it without restart, for example.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Per @Tiernan's comment, on PostgreSQL 10 and newer this issue is no longer present.

On older versions 9.6 and below: There is no workaround. You must restart the server.

Comment: For future reference, this limitation only exists on 9.x and below. postgresql 10 and newer support reloading certificates. A workaround these days could be "upgrade to a newer version of postgres".